# hex color calculator: change color for twitter bootstrap buttons

Tags: css, button, colors, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser

OK, I'm trying to rewrite the color for Twitter Bootstrap buttons (for example, for `.btn-primary`).

As far as I see, there are several colors that are defined for .btn-primary so they have all fixes for all browsers.

The easiest way I see it to write all the colors for .btn-primary and "move" them to the same difference as new basic color is differ from the basic color of btn-primary, that is actually `#006dcc` as I see from `bootstrap.css`.

Is there a calculator to easily change the color like:

```
newcolor=(006ecc-006dcc)+aaaaaa=aaabaa
```

so that I shoudn't split each color into 3 hex numbers and find the difference for each 3 pairs of each color?

Or, is there any easier correct way to change color with keeping gradients, hovers, fixes for all browsers for Twitter Bootstrap buttons?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Less can do math on colors:  see "Functions & Operations" on http://www.lesscss.org/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This site appears to be down at the moment, but I've found it quite handy (when it's working): http://charliepark.org/bootstrap_buttons/

Hopefully there's just a temp issue with the site.

Comment: Yes, that looks the best solution among the possible ones.

Answer (score 2):

Try [http://twitterbootstrapbuttons.w3masters.nl/?color=%23006dcc](http://twitterbootstrapbuttons.w3masters.nl/?color=#006dcc) you can enter your html color code (hexadecimal) and get three variations of buttons (dark, light, spin).